# Поиск на Google Apps Script

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Требуется реализовать поиск с помощью Google Apps Script следующим образом:

1. В таблице выделяется строка с данными (ФИО и ID),
2. При нажатии на кнопку скрипт должен найти в другой таблице строку, содержащую эти данные, и удалить её.

Как лучше это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Код ниже необходимо добавить в Таблицу, в которой находится список.

- SPREADSHEET_ID_FOR_DELETING - id Таблицы из которой необходимо удалять
- SHEET_NAME_FOR_DELETING - имя Листа, из которого необходимо удалять

#### Code.gs

```
// Создает меню    
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Удалятор').addItem('Удалить из Данных', 'remove').addToUi();
}

//Основная функция
function remove() {

  // id Таблицы из которой необходимо удалять
  var SPREADSHEET_ID_FOR_DELETING = 'abcdefghi123456';
  // имя Листа, из которого необходимо удалять
  var SHEET_NAME_FOR_DELETING = 'Sheet1';

  // Определяем активный диапазон, для того чтобы можно было удалять одновременно несколько строк
  var ar = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var rowStart = ar.getRow();
  var rowEnd = ar.getLastRow();

  var activeValues = ar.getSheet().getRange(rowStart, 1, rowEnd - rowStart + 1, 2).getValues();

  // Лист из которого будем удалять
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID_FOR_DELETING).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME_FOR_DELETING);
  // Массив для обхода
  var dataValues = dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Обход данных для удаления. В обратном порядке из-за необходимости удалять
  for (var i = dataValues.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // Текущее значение индекса 
    var current = dataValues[i][0] + dataValues[i][1];
      // Обход значений из выделенного диапазона
      for (var j = 0; j < activeValues.length; j++) {
      // Если текущий индекс совпадает со значением выделенного диапазона необходимо удалить строку
      if (current === (activeValues[j][0] + activeValues[j][1])) {
        dataSheet.deleteRow(i + 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Пример

[Директория](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bztea6vSatozMWxKZC1ILXNhdWM?usp=sharing) с файлами. Необходимо сделать копию и прописать свои значения переменных. В рабочей Таблице находится формула `IMPORTRANGE`, которая берет данные из Таблицы Данные, для аутентичности.